# can't get text from EditText and display it to TextView

Tags: android-studio-2.1

i am very new to programming language.  and in android studio, I am trying to get text from EditText display it on TextView when the user press the button. but it goes wrong. anyone help me? please, thanks.

```
TextView welcome_lbl;
EditText enter_text;
Button welcome_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    welcome_lbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_lbl);
    enter_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_text);
    welcome_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcome_btn);

    welcome_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            welcome_lbl.setText(enter_text.getText().length());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> String text = enter_text.getText.toString();
>
> welcome_lbl.setText(text);

Or with your way,

> welcome_lbl.setText(enter_text.getText.toString());